# How can I create a PostgreSQL db-f1-micro instance?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

In the [Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL pricing examples](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pricing#pg-examples), I see that I should be able to create a `db-f1-micro` instance, using a shared CPU and 0.6 GB of RAM, at the price of $9/month.

However, when I try to actually create such an instance, I don't see that option. The UI only allows me to create a custom machine type with at least 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB of RAM, which would cost $51/month:

[image: Screenshot of Cloud Console creating a PostgreSQL instance]

Interestingly, for MySQL, I *do* get the option to create a `db-f1-micro` instance. But I can't use MySQL for this project.

Are the docs in error here? Or is there a trick to actually creating a budget `db-f1-micro` instance using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce Google Cloud SQL instance size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737635/how-to-reduce-google-cloud-sql-instance-size)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aha, I *was* missing a trick: the **Cores** slider isn't all the way on the left! Dragging it down sets it to "1 shared vCPU" and changes the memory settings to my satisfaction:

[image: Screenshot of vCPU setting]

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I was surprised this is so hidden away in the UI, considering it's such an important setting. For anyone else who can't find it, it's in one of the expandable boxes in advanced settings.

Comment: @davnicwil you have any idea how much the 1.7GB memory option is?

Comment: @ChadScira I think most of the prices for the various options are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: @davnicwil I got it, I wish they made the instance type more transparent when you modify the options or at least show a pricing breakdown of the config you selected without having to reference the pricing matrix.

Comment: So predatory to hide it that way. How much extra money did they charge all due to people not knowing the minimum default instance is actually a relatively expensive instance? Just another effective mix of growth marketing tactics and revenue maximization. Would be nice if we had an effective regulatory body to actually police and fine for this egregious behavior.

Comment: "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity."

Answer (score 1):

Also you can change it with CLI via `gcloud`:

```
gcloud sql instances patch <instance name here> --tier db-f1-micro
```